# prestashop cookies exceed 4ko

Tags: cookies, browser, prestashop

I have a problem with a prestashop project.
prestashop creates cookie that exceed the maximum size authorized (4ko)
I have no idea which module or controller or something create that cookie.

Can you help me to make these cookies smaller or find which controller created these?

```
Cookie: cp-popup-last-displayed=1662364477; axeptio_cookies={%22$$token%22:%22borew4apbudam6j1zuean%22%2C%22$$date%22:%222022-05-05T07:44:01.399Z%22%2C%22$$completed%22:true%2C%22google_analytics%22:true%2C%22Google_Ads%22:true%2C%22GoogleRemarketing%22:true%2C%22facebook_pixel%22:true%2C%22SendinBlue%22:true}; axeptio_authorized_vendors=%2Cgoogle_analytics%2CGoogle_Ads%2CGoogleRemarketing%2Cfacebook_pixel%2CSendinBlue%2C; axeptio_all_vendors=%2Cgoogle_analytics%2CGoogle_Ads%2CGoogleRemarketing%2Cfacebook_pixel%2CSendinBlue%2C; PrestaShop-d354edfaf436c62a4b18afdcf0ba8174=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; PHPSESSID=8oeegu4ns8ok86aef2jachr6ml; cp-popup-61=1662364312; cp-popup-63=1662364477; PrestaShop-1875e1269d17c82b34ad3c945ac1416b=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
```

Answer (score 1):

Prestashop Cookie is being encrypted when sent to client

(see your *PrestaShop-d354edfaf436c62a4b18afdcf0ba8174=def50200037b619c0f4...*
is the whole encypted cookie content)

You'll have to debug this "server side" by checking the **Cookie.php** class and dumping the $cookie object in the *_setcookie()* method
before it getting encrypted.

Comment: Hey, thanks for answer, sorry for late reply, after trying your solution i found a cookie the weight is 1.95ko before encrypt and 3.9 after encrypt, the module that take the most of weight is dpdfrance_relais_cookie, this module store all adresses the customer have set to delivery in a cookie. on the configuration page of the module i dont see any cookies settings options, any solution for this ?

Comment: Well, avoid to use that specific module or have it store data somewhere else :)

Answer (score 1):

It is probably because of the *Last viewed* module. This product stores too many modules inside the Cookie. Do you use this module?

Comment: hey, after taking a look about it, indeed ps_viewed_product take some place dpd france take that much but reduce viewed products could be enought maybe... do you know a solution to reduce number of id product stored by viewed product ?

Comment: There's a WIP, but you can get a solution: https://github.com/PrestaShop/ps_viewedproduct/pull/25

Comment: there is something i dont understand : to debug ps_viewedproduct i uninstalled this module, cleared prestashop cache, cleared cookie browser, i steel have the product id from viewed product on my cookie. What did i miss about it ?

Comment: this change makes sure that you won't have more than X products inside the cookie, the problem was that previously there was no limit :)

Comment: i tried this solution but it didnt work, it is just like the code i type is not read, And then, to be sure i just uninstalled the module, even with the module uninstalled the viewed product are still recorded on the cookie. I have edit modules/ps_viewedproduct but my changes have no effect.

Comment: They should be recorded. That's a "feature", not a "bug". The difference is that only a few of them will be stored in the Cookie, which should solve your problem :)

Comment: i just found, i have misunderstanding something, indeed on my cookies i had a list of product but it was not generated by ps_viewedproduct, there is another module named ets_crosssell, and this module also record id products. i just limited number of product recorded on this other module